# Adding highchart3d in Angular 6 application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, highcharts, web-applications

I am trying to add highcharts3d in Angular 6 application. How to use highchart3d in application to display chart in 3d format. It gives compilation error after import of highchart3d library as follows:

import Highcharts3d from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d';

Thanks,

Comment: What compilation error?

Comment: Are you using pure Highcharts in your angualr app, or using official wrapper to build your charts? Here is the example which shows the way of use wrapper: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-cloning-chart-j49cza

Answer (score 0):

Install angular2-highcharts from npm:

`npm install angular2-highcharts --save`

Setup in App Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { App } from './App';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule, 
      ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts')
    ],
    declarations: [App],
    bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And use it in the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'simple-chart-example',
    template: `
        <chart [options]="options"></chart>
    `
})
export class App {
    constructor() {
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
            }]
        };
    }
    options: Object;
}
```

Read more here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#add-highcharts-modules